# angularjs remove $scope.expression from ng-src

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a image from a angular scope that is placed over my background image in a from, when i submit the form i clear the data from the form, however the image remains. How would i be able to remove the image from the $scope and just see the background image again.

This is the code (example)

```
<form ng-submit=submitform()>
  <input type="text" ng-model="formdata.gametitle">
  <input type="text" ng-model="formdata.image">
  <img ng-src="{{formdata.image}}" style="background-image: 'url("select.jpg")'; width: 5vw; height: 7vw;"/>
<input type="submit">
```

so what this does it that the user adds a suggested image in the input (formdata.image) as an html link, in that case the  directly shows the
image on the screen. When the user clicks the submit button i wipe the formdata clean (after adding it to the db first of course) as such

```
$scope.formdata = [];
```

this clears all the input fields, however the image stays. I can do this as example:

```
$scope.formdata.image = "//:0" // broken image link displayed
$scope.formdata.image = "" // does not do anything
$scope.formdata.image = $0; // results in crash
$scope.formdata.image = null; // no result
```

How would i be able to remove the complete data from the formfield and remove the image display, i don't want to 'ng-hide' the complete image i just want to show the image that is in the background. When one first time loads the form the DevTools elements mentions, you can reference to this expression with ==$0, "use $0 in the console.log to refer to this element" it say's. In this case there is no data.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces the issue. Can click on `<>` in editor to create one right here in the page

Comment: You can use `$scope.formdata={};`

Comment: @Feras: it displays the broken image link/icon as such <img class="SuggestImage" ng-src="{}" src="{}"

Answer (score 0):

To be able to clear all the data of a form one could use the $destroy.

```
$scope.formdata.$destroy
```